# Return false messing with php action in html form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently in the works of making a website. However, I've hit a snag. I'm using php to POST and put data filled out in a form into a database. I've also got a script in the page to display the contents of the form below so users can copy and paste the output which is reformatted if they'd like. But they don't work together.

webpage code:

```
<div class="hero-text col col--2-3">
  <form class="signup-form" action="includes/newref.inc.php" method="POST" name="myform" id="myform"  onsubmit="formFunction(); return false;">
    <h6>Reference!</h6>
    Author: <input type="text" name="author" style="text-transform: capitalize;" value="John Doe" required="1"><br>
    Year created: <input type="text" name="yearcreated" value="13/04/2018" required="1"><br>
    Title: <input type="text" name="title" style="text-transform: capitalize;" value="To make the best pizza" required="1"><br>
    URL: <input type="text" name="url" value="www.example.com"><br>
    Last Accessed: <input type="text" name="lastaccessed" value="05/04/2018" required="1"><br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Create</button>
    <button type="reset" name="clear">Clear</button>

    <script>
      function formFunction(){
        var author = document.myform.author.value;
        var yearcreated = document.myform.yearcreated.value;
        var title = document.myform.title.value;
        var url = document.myform.url.value;
        var lastaccessed = document.myform.lastaccessed.value;
        var showData = "- " + author + ". " + yearcreated + ". " + title + ". " + url + ". " + "[Last Accessed: " + lastaccessed + "].";
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = showData;
      }
    </script>
  </form>

  <div class="Copy">
    <h6>Copy Here!</h6>
  <div id="output"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

PHP CODE:

```
     <?php
#first if
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'dbhref.inc.php';

    $author = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['author']);
    $yearcreated = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['yearcreated']);
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['title']);
    $url = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['url']);
    $lastaccessed = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['lastaccessed']);

  //Error handelers
    //Check for empty field
    #if
    if (empty($author) || empty($yearcreated) || empty($title) || empty($url) || empty($lastaccessed)) {
    header("Location: ../create.php?creation=empty");
    exit();
  } /*else*/ else {
        //Insert the user into the database
      $sql = "INSERT INTO reference (r_author, r_yearcreated, r_title, r_url, r_lastaccessed) VALUES ('$author','$yearcreated','$title','$url','$lastaccessed');";
      mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
            header("Location: ../create.php?-success");
      exit();
    }
} /*else*/ else {
    header("Location: ../create.php?=error");
    exit();
}
```

The problem lays with the `onsubmit="formFunction(); return false;"`
however, that is needed to keep the output on screen as when turned to true, the output will just display then disapear in a second. 
I'm just wondering if there is another way of doing this where they both work?

Thanks you, I appreciate any help :)

Comment: This is what AJAX is for, you can read up on it on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest (the article has a section dedicated to submitting forms)

Comment: @MátéSafranka is there an added benefit of using AJAX? But thanks I'll have a read :)

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly (i.e. you want to send data to the server without actually submitting the form), then this is the only way to make it work.

Comment: I want to do both, submit the form to the db and also display the output of what was filled in the form.

Comment: "Submitting the form" means loading the page specified in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element, which will replace the currently viewed page. That's why your form disappears.

Comment: The code in the state I've posted above shows the data in the form below the form, which I want. But it doesn't submit the form to the db.

If the 'onSubmit="formFunction(); return false;"' is changed to true, this posts the data to the db, but doesn't display the data below the form.

Comment: @MátéSafranka I think this is happening because in the PHP code I have `header("Location:../create.php?=success);` and then `exit();` - could this be refreshing the page and therefore, removing the javascript output?

Answer (score 0):

This is what AJAX is for. Remove the `onsubmit` attribute from the `<form>` tag and try this:

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
myform.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formdata = new FormData(myform);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', myform.action);
    xhr.send(formdata);

    var author = myform.author.value;
    var yearcreated = myform.yearcreated.value;
    var title = myform.title.value;
    var url = myform.url.value;
    var lastaccessed = myform.lastaccessed.value;
    var showData = "- " + author + ". " + yearcreated + ". " + title + ". " + url + ". " + "[Last Accessed: " + lastaccessed + "].";
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = showData;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: So after replacing the JavaScript with this still presents the same problem :/

Comment: Edited my answer, can you try this?

Comment: When you test this code, try opening the browser console with Ctrl+Shift+I, switch to the Network tab and check if the HTTP request is sent to the server when you submit the form.

Comment: I'll post my PHP code above, this will better explain. But the code above still has the same issue, the data is shown below the form, but doesn't post tot he db.

Comment: That can either be an issue on the client side (i.e. the javascript code) or the server side (the PHP code). The reason I'm asking you to check the network traffic in your browser is to make sure the javascript code is working as it should.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure the problem is that sending the form data via AJAX doesn't include the buttons, i.e. `isset($_POST['submit'])` will not be true.